# Python and beautiful soup: Extract data from a specific set of list in unordered list category

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to go to [this](http://biotechlab.fudan.edu.cn/database/lamp/detail.php?id=L01A003388) page, and scrape all of the lines in the 'activity' tab:

```
  Antibacterial Activities
  1  Flora:E.coli  MIC:5.59µg/ml  (2.0005µM)  Method:MIC  :
  2  Flora:A.salmonicida subsp salmonicida  MIC:11.18µg/ml  (4.001µM)  Method:MIC  :
  3  Flora:V.anguillarum  MIC:2.79µg/ml  (0.998461µM)  Method:MIC  :
  4  Flora:S.typhimurium  MIC:11.18µg/ml  (4.001µM)  Method:MIC  :
  5  Flora:B.subtilis  MIC:5.59µg/ml  (2.0005µM)  Method:MIC  :
  6  Flora:L.ivanovii  MIC:11.18µg/ml  (4.001µM)  Method:MIC  :
```

I was trying different methods with beautifulsoup, because I was struggling too much doing it with selenium. The different methods that I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html_page = urlopen('http://biotechlab.fudan.edu.cn/database/lamp/detail.php?id=L01A003388')
soup = bs(html_page)



#method 1
li = soup.select('ul')
print(li)



#method 2
for ultag in soup.find_all('ul',{'class':"ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active"}):
        for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
                print(litag.text)



#method 3
for ul in soup.findAll('ul', class_="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active"):
    for link in ul.findAll('a'):
        print(link.text)
```

Method 1 prints all of the UL, whereas I only want this part returned in a nicer format:

```
<ul><li><strong>  Antibacterial Activities</strong></li><li>  1  Flora:E.coli  MIC:5.59µg/ml  (2.0005µM)  Method:MIC  :</li><li>  2  Flora:A.salmonicida subsp salmonicida  MIC:11.18µg/ml  (4.001µM)  Method:MIC  :</li><li>  3  Flora:V.anguillarum  MIC:2.79µg/ml  (0.998461µM)  Method:MIC  :</li><li>  4  Flora:S.typhimurium  MIC:11.18µg/ml  (4.001µM)  Method:MIC  :</li><li>  5  Flora:B.subtilis  MIC:5.59µg/ml  (2.0005µM)  Method:MIC  :</li><li>  6  Flora:L.ivanovii  MIC:11.18µg/ml  (4.001µM)  Method:MIC  :</li></ul>
```

Method 2 and method 3 both just returned 'soup = bs(html_page)' printed to the screen.

If someone could show me where I'm going wrong/how to extract the data of interest I would appreciate it. As a side note, I am only learning, I was originally trying to do this with selenium, but i struggled with it which is why I've moved to beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use `:contains` to target the `Activity` tab and use [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to get next `div` and [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) with [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) to get child `li`. I use `re` to do some string cleaning for output.

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://biotechlab.fudan.edu.cn/database/lamp/detail.php?id=L01A003388')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
items = [re.sub('(\xa0)+',' ',i.text.strip()) for i in soup.select('h3:contains(Activity) + div li')]
print(items)
```

---

Output:

[image]